# find a Float value not over another value haskell

Tags: haskell

I have to find a height that's not taller than a given value. I have found code that does it for a list of integers. But I need it to accept a float value i.e. `countElems :: Float -> Heights -> Int`. I know I have to use fromIntegral to allow a Float value but I don't know how to implement it. This is what I have so far:

```
countElems :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
countElems n (x:xs) = fromEnum (n < x) + countElems n xs
countElems _ []     = 0
```

Comment: What is `Heights`?  Can you describe your problem in more detail, assuming that we don't know anything about the problem you're trying to solve (since we don't)?

Comment: it's a list of integers imported via countElems 150 (tall_short)

Comment: could you explain why and how it's done as my teacher can hardly speak English and can't teach a kinder gardener to cry.

Comment: Did you try googling "haskell convert float to int"?  The top 2 links should explain how to do this.

Comment: Do you need to make the same but for `Float` type like `countElems :: Float -> [Float] -> Int`?

Comment: yes wowofbob, that's correct. I have been trying to google it all night bheklilr to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Just edit `countElems` type annotation to accept any ordered type:

```
countElems :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> Int
countElems n (x:xs) = fromEnum (n < x) + countElems n xs
countElems _ []     = 0
```

Now it works both for `Int` and `Float` and for every instance of `Ord` type class.

Actually, it's an actual type of `countElems` which compiler infers. Your version is restricted only for `a = Float`.

Comment: This would be a lot more idiomatic as `countElems n xs = length . filter (n <) xs`, as an extra tip to @caz.

Comment: Thanks I will experiment with ordered type when I get up in the morning. Thank you for you help. That's a new approach I've not been taught yet. @bheklilr

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using:

`countElems :: Float -> [Float] -> Int
 countElems _ [] = 0
 countElems n (x:xs)
   | n < x = 1 + (tallerthan n xs)
   | otherwise = tallerthan n xs`